# Problem deleting error duplicate values from list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm creating a syntax to find duplicate values, combine values, and remove duplicate values.
It works well but does not specify a range of values in the last column.
What do you think is wrong?

The table I used is as below.

```
code1   2
code1   6
code1   2
code2   4
code2   5
code3   6
code3   6
```

The resulting values are as follows.

```
print(overlap)

[5, 6]

print(first_index)
5

print(second_index)
6

####Code1, code2 is exactly the range.#####
####The value in this syntax should be [5:6], but 6 is output.####
print(qty[first_index:second_index]) 
    [6]

qty.insert(overlap[0],sum_qty)
    print(qty)
    [2, 6, 2, 4, 5, 12, 6]
```

Here is code.

```
find_code = code3
overlap = (find_index(code,find_code))
first_index = overlap[0]
second_index = overlap[-1]
if overlap[0] > -1:
    sum_qty_ele = []
    for ele in overlap:
        sum_qty_ele.append(qty[ele])
    del qty[first_index:second_index]
    sum_qty = sum(sum_qty_ele)
    qty.insert(overlap[0],sum_qty)
    print(qty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In list slicing the stop value is not included so what you may need to do is adding 1 to second_index to include second_index itself in the deletion:

```
if overlap[0] > -1:
    sum_qty_ele = []
    for ele in overlap:
        sum_qty_ele.append(qty[ele])
    print(qty[first_index:second_index])
    del qty[first_index:second_index+1]
    sum_qty = sum(sum_qty_ele)
    qty.insert(overlap[0],sum_qty)
    print(qty)
```